# Jasmine function Spy doesn't work with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an angular-cli project with the following test suite:

```
let fakeCellService = {
  getCellOEE: function (value): Observable<Array<IOee>> {
    return Observable.of([{ time: moment(), val: 67 }, { time: moment(), val: 78 }]);
  }
};

describe('Oee24Component', () => {
  let component: any;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Oee24Component>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Oee24Component],
      providers: [{ provide: CellService, useValue: fakeCellService }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Oee24Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(fakeCellService, 'getCellOEE');
  });

  it('should get cell oee on init', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(fakeCellService.getCellOEE).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

However, the Spy in the test fails. I know the function is called, as I tested this in a debugger. I can't see how this differs from the documented examples, but presumably it does! Any ideas why?

Here is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-oee',
  templateUrl: './oee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./oee.component.css']
})
export class Oee24Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dataService: CellService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getCellOEE(this.cell).subscribe(value => this.updateChart(value));
  }

  updateChart(data: Array<IOee>) {
      //Logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to use `fakeCellService` use original service and original service values will be replaced by fake service. Its called mocking

Comment: @BabarBilal How should I approach this then?

Comment: Use injector from angular/core then inject your CellService into a variable like you did with component and then spy any method from it you can use injector like `injector.get(CellService)`

Comment: Please show your component

Comment: @peeskillet I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First inject the `Injector`

```
 import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
 import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
```

Create service variable (below your component variable )

```
let service : CellService;
let injector : Injector;
```

Inject it after testbed process ( just below your component instance)

```
injector = getTestBed();
service = injector.get(CellService)
```

Now you can spy it

```
spyOn(service, 'YourMethod').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });
```

Let me know if any confusion here is your working describe section code

```
describe('Oee24Component', () => {
 let component: any;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<Oee24Component>;
 let injector: Injector;
 let service: CellService;


 beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [Oee24Component],
   providers: [{ provide: CellService, useValue: fakeCellService }]
  })
  .compileComponents();
 }));

 beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Oee24Component);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  injector = getTestBed();
  service = injector.get(CellService)
  fixture.detectChanges();
  spyOn(service, 'getCellOEE').and.returnValue({ subscribe : () => {} });
 });

 it('should get cell oee on init', () => {
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(service.getCellOEE).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The `service = injector.get(CellService)` throws error, `Cannot find name 'injector'`, If I change it to `Injector.get(...` then I get error, `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'typeof Injector'`

Comment: Oh one sec you have to initialize injector as well let me update the answer

Comment: I have done this, but I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` which suggests my mock service isn't returning an observable in the way I expected? I have added the component to my question

Comment: now that is RxJS issue your module don't know your service is going to return an observable so yu have to mock that as well I'm updating answer again just spy line changes

Comment: Thanks! Finally, what should my expect look like? At the moment `expect(fakeCellService.getCellOEE).toHaveBeenCalled();` throws the error -`Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function. Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: again why you are using `fakeCellService` to spy as I earlier said that is mock let me add whole code in answer

Comment: This is working for me now - Thank you! I am not sure I fully have my head around this approach yet though... see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135596/spy-on-the-result-of-an-observable-subscription-with-jasmine?noredirect=1#comment73349679_43135596)