# Spy on the result of an Observable Subscription with Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am Jasmine unit testing an angular component, which uses Observables. My component has this lifecycle hook that I am testing:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getCellOEE(this.cell).subscribe(value => this.updateChart(value));
}
```

I have a test that ensures that getCellOEE has been called, but now I want to check that updateChart is called when the observable resolves with a new value. This is what I have so far:

```
let fakeCellService = {
  getCellOEE: function (value): Observable<Array<IOee>> {
    return Observable.of([{ time: moment(), val: 67 }, { time: moment(), val: 78 }]);
  }
};

describe('Oee24Component', () => {
  let component: Oee24Component;
  let service: CellService;
  let injector: Injector;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Oee24Component>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Oee24Component],
      providers: [{ provide: CellService, useValue: fakeCellService }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Oee24Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(CellService)
    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(service, 'getCellOEE').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => { } });
    spyOn(component, 'updateChart');
  });

  it('should get cell oee on init', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(service.getCellOEE).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should update chart on new data', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.updateChart).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

However, I get the error:

> chrome 56.0.2924 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Oee24Component should update chart on new data FAILED
>
> Expected spy updateChart to have been called.

Presumably this is a timing issue because the observable hasn't necessarily resolved when the test checks? If that is the case, how do I set this up correctly?

## Update:

Here is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-oee24',
  templateUrl: './oee24.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./oee24.component.css']
})
export class Oee24Component implements OnInit {
  public barChartData: any[] = [{ data: [], label: 'OEE' }];

  constructor(public dataService: CellService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getCellOEE(this.cell).subscribe(value => this.updateChart(value));
  }

  updateChart(data: Array<IOee>) {
    this.barChartData[0].data = data.map(val => val.val);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're spying on your service, and making it return a fake observable, whose subscribe() method does nothing (and thus never calls the callback passed to subscribe()). Just don't do that.

Comment: @JBNizet What should I be doing?

Comment: I'm not sure how spying on `.subscribe` gets you what you say you want. You're already spying on the function you want to test is actually getting called, and the `Observable.of` provides data for it. You don't need to explicitly check that the subscription happens; if it doesn't, that data won't get to `updateChart`. Instead try checking *what* `updateChart` is called with, so you can check it's the right data given the observable you've built.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to check `updateChart` is called, but I agree seeing what it is called with would be handy, but then my test as shown above is still failing?This is why I thought I needed to look at the subscription to try and resolve any timing issue?

Comment: do share your component code ^^

Comment: @BabarBilal Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever come up with a solution?  What about using the `jasmine-marbles` package and the `complete` event?

```
it('should update chart on new data', () => {
    const obs$ = cold('--a-|');
    spyOn(service, 'getCellOEE').and.returnValue(obs$);
    component.ngOnInit(); 
    obs$.subscribe({
        complete: () => {
            expect(component.updateChart).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is this method `const obs$ = cold('--a-|');` here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I've seen it working on a project I'm working on. The approach is basically get a reference to the callback function provided to the subscribe method, and call it manually to simulate the observer emitting a value:

```
it('should update chart on new data', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();

    // this is your mocked observable
    const obsObject = service.getCellOEE.calls.mostRecent().returnValue;

    // expect(obsObject.subscribe).toHaveBeenCalled() should pass

    // get the subscribe callback function you provided in your component code
    const subscribeCb = obsObject.subscribe.calls.mostRecent().args[0];

    // now manually call that callback, you can provide an argument here to mock the "value" returned by the service
    subscribeCb(); 

    expect(component.updateChart).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
spyOn(service, 'getCellOEE').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => { } });
```

You could try

```
spyOn(service, 'getCellOEE').and.returnValue( {subscribe: (callback) => callback()});
```

Answer (score 0):

`fixture.detectChanges` triggers `ngOnInit`. so, no need to call `ngOnInit` manually if `fixture.detectChanges` was executed.

It's a bad practice [to check if the method was called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68271135/unit-test-a-method-called-from-a-method/68418754#68418754). Instead, it is more reliable to check the expected results of the code execution.

There is no need in the line `spyOn(service, 'getCellOEE').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => { } });` because `fakeCellService` already mocks properly the service.

The tested code is async, so we need to wait till it would be executed. `await fixture.whenStable();` does exactly this.

So, the resulting test:

```js
const fakeData = [{ time: moment(), val: 67 }, { time: moment(), val: 78 }];
const expectedChartData = [67, 78];
const fakeCellService = {
  getCellOEE: function (value): Observable<Array<IOee>> {
    return Observable.of(fakeData);
  }
};

describe('Oee24Component', () => {
  let component: Oee24Component;
  let service: CellService;
  let injector: Injector;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Oee24Component>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Oee24Component],
      providers: [{ provide: CellService, useValue: fakeCellService }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Oee24Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
  });

  it('maps and saves value from the CellService.getCellOEE to barChartData[0].data when initialized', () => {
    expect(component.barChartData[0].data).toEqual(expectedChartData);
  });
});
```