# how to spy on observable variable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, ngrx

The `ng-cli` generated test case `should create` is failing with following error:

`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

I track down the line that was causing an error that is in my HTML I have

**items.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="items$ | async as items">
   <input vaule="{{ items.colors.length }}" name="colors_count" /> Colors
</div>
```

Inside the component I have:

**items.component.ts**

```
import * as fromItems from '../state';  
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
        items$: Observable<Item>;

        ngOnInit(): void {
          this.items$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromItems.getCurrentItem));
        }
    }
```

**items.component.spec.ts**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ItemModule, TestsModule ],
      providers: [
        ItemService,
        NgForm,
        ItemsEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions),
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  const item = new Item();
  item.colors = [];

beforeEach(async(() => {
    const id = '001318e4-b6f2-47d9-8816-c50a7b545784';
    effects = TestBed.get(ItemsEffects);
    const action = new itemActions.Load(id);
    const completion = new itemActions.LoadSuccess(item);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ItemsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.items$ = of(item);

    const service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ItemService);
    spyOn(service, 'getItem').and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();

    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));
```

I am using ngrx-store to set the variable `item$` inside `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

While testing, I am trying to set the blank array in the `item.colors` to resolve the above mention `length` error that is causing spec to fail.

But, set value for `item.colors` from testing is getting overwritten by the lifecycle hook `ngOnInit`.

So, Is there any way I can spy on `items$` to wait for the value to load and set again in testing suit?

Comment: You could use `{{ items.colors?.length }}` to avoid the error.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes, this can be a solutions but I am trying to resolve it within `spec` file. As I do not think it will be appropriate to change the code file to make the unit testing pass.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135596/spy-on-the-result-of-an-observable-subscription-with-jasmine check if this is relevant.