# Unit test a method called from a method

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an angular application and a method that gets provoked on click. In this method I am passing a value to another private method.

**.ts file**

```
public onViewItem(item: Results): void {
    const ids = [item.data['id']];
    this.anotherMethod(ids);
}
```

**.spec file**

```
it('should trigger a method on view item', () => {
    component.onViewItem(documents[0]);
    expect(component.onViewItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

How do I test the line `const ids = [item.data['id']];` and check the call of `this.anotherMethod(ids);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good practice for it: check the expected results and avoid checking which method is being called in between. It would make the test easy to maintain.

Let's explore it with an example.

```js
public onViewItem(item: Results): void {
    const ids = [item.data['id']];
    this.anotherMethod(ids);
}
public anotherMethod(ids: number[]): void {
    this.ids = ids;
}
```

What are the options to test it? I see two:

**Bad one**

Spy on the `anotherMethod`:

```js
it('should trigger a method on view item', () => {
    spyOn(NameOfTheComponent, 'anotherMethod')
    
    component.onViewItem(documents[0]);

    expect(component.anotherMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith([documents[0].id]);
});
```

**Good one**

Test the expected results:

```js
it('should trigger a method on view item', () => {
    spyOn(NameOfTheComponent, 'anotherMethod')
    
    component.onViewItem(documents[0]);

    expect(component.ids).toEqual([documents[0].id]);
});
```

Why is the good one better? Consider you refactored the `onViewItem` method. Now it looks like this:

```js
public onViewItem(item: Results): void {
    const ids = [item.data['id']];
    this.ids = ids;
}
```

The arguments are the same. Results yielded by the method execution exactly the same as well. if you had a spy on the function you are forced to refactor the test. If you just tested the expected results - you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to spy on the method you want to ensure the parameters.

```js
spyOn(NameOfTheComponent, 'anotherMethod')
expect(NameOfTheComponent.anotherMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith([IDEXPECTED])
```

Comment: Will this work if `anotherMethod` is private? What I would do is what does `anotherMethod` do at the end of the day (does it paint the background green, does it show a popup notification, etc.) and ensure what it does at the end of the day is proper and assert it.

Comment: If another method is private, you should try to make test cases to cover it indirectly, and you can spy on public variables or methods to check their value or if they were called